# Experiment for jammers

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, experimental-physics, interference

I'm going to grade 11 and I have to write an essay in physics. One requirement is to do an experiment which - in the best case - also includes measurements.

I would like to write about jammers, which cut connections by interference signals. Since it is not legal, I will not build or use a real jammer.

Instead I am searching for an experiment that demonstrates how jammers work.

Can anyone help me with finding a good but practical experiment? ;)

Best regards
Julius

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to a laboratory with a [water wave channel](https://www.3bscientific.com/water-wave-channel-1000807-u8431411-3b-scientific,p_835_1994.html)?

If yes, you could reproduce this [soliton experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLdOEcaS1uI) . Solitons are [wavepackets](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html), and one could use them sequentially  to carry information, a Morse code for example, dependent on the distance between them.

Jamming could be a water sprout , disturbing the flow of information.

If you do not have access to a lab, you could reproduce an effect of sending a coded message by water disturbance by using a trough, and  creating the wave packet by letting marbles fall at the beginning of the water line, with time distance between falls creating the Morse code..

Comment: marbles are heavy and can accumulate where they fall without disturming the signal

Comment: Thanks a lot for you idea. Unfortunately I do not have a lab and I am not able to reproduce water waves.
I can only reproduce simple experiments that don‘t require a big setup.

Comment: You do not need a lab for the last paragraph.setup. You just need a rectangular pan with water and marbles. You could time the drops with a watch, five seconds for a dot ten seconds for a dash.Any distrubance that would disperse the packet and change the timing, like a water hose, would jam the morse signal.

Comment: Alright. I think I got the idea. But as I just found out, water waves are apparently not comparable to electromagnetic waves as they can get through each other and there is no destructive interference. This article is in German but the first animation shows the phenomenon when waves collide: http://www.dieter-heidorn.de/Physik/SS/K03_Wellen/K02_Interferenz/K02_Interferenz.html

Comment: true, but the water experiment will show the same damage to information transfer as  jamming electromagnetic waves that transfer information. If there was no interest in the information , nobody would worry about jamming. So it depends if you want to use the mathematice of electromagnetic waves you have to use electromagnetic waves, because all other waves that can carry information depend on the mediium that carries their energy.

Comment: you could try a morse code with the flashlight of you mobile. The jamming would be shining a flaschlite to hide  the sequence.

Comment: How would it change the information of the water wave? Aren't the properties of the wave (including the amplitude) the same after the collision?

Comment: water waves collide means that the atoms/molecules of the water collide with each other. Electromagnetic waves do not collide, they pass through each other.. It is a complicated mathematical system based on maxwell equations.

Comment: The signal is carried by the light waves as the interference pattern that appears when same frequency light overlaps.( Interference is not collision). If that interference pattern , carrying voice information fore example, is distroyed by other light of the same frequency then the information it carries is jammed, i.e. destroyed. It needs mathematics to understand it.